# Is it possible to create a game on CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd, console-application

Can games be created to run on the Command Prompt?

Comment: [definitively possible](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4741) - besides text based games of course.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in "*batch*" files or "*.bat*". These can be created in Notepad. If you are strictly wanting to stay in Command Prompt though you could try "*copy con C:\anywhere\anyname.bat*" and what ever you type will be saved in that file after pressing *CTRL+Z* when done.

So in theory....

Create the file first. **copy con C:\movegame.bat**
Enter the following code.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
title movement
color 0a

set length=         
set height= a

:controls
cls
echo Use WASD to move your character ([]).
echo.
for %%a in ( %height% ) do echo.
echo %length%[]
choice /c wasd /n
if %errorlevel% equ 1 call:up
if %errorlevel% equ 2 call:left
if %errorlevel% equ 3 call:down
if %errorlevel% equ 4 call:right

:left
set length=!length:~0,-1!
goto controls

:right
set length=%length%
goto controls

:up
set height=!height:~0,-2!
goto controls

:down
set height=%height% a
goto control
```

**CTRL+Z** (This will save the file)

Then you can run the batch file. WASD to move.
***C:\movegame.bat***

So much more can be done, this is simply 29 lines. Check out the following article about the above batch file.

[Batch Game Movement (Tutorial)](http://www.instructables.com/id/Batch-game-movement-simple/)

If you are looking for ideas or inspiration, try out [Zork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zork). It's all text based adventure. QBasic or Basic may interest you as well.